# What kind of Romulan warbirds was the Enterprise-C fighting?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the *Star Trek: TNG* episode "Yesterday's Enterprise," Captain Garrett [tells Captain Picard](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/163.htm) that the Enterprise-C was attacked by four Romulan warbirds. However, she never specified what class of warbirds they were. Is there any source (hopefully as close to canon as possible) indicating what class they were?
There is one fan-made YouTube video depicting the Battle at Narendra III; in the video, the warbirds belonged to the D'deridex class, but this is probably unrealistic. If the Enterprise-C had faced off against four of those ships, it simply couldn't have survived long enough to make it through the temporal rift. Could the warbirds have been the smaller ones like those seen in *Star Trek: TOS?*

Comment: Note the Romulan saucer ships in TOS are bird-of-preys.  Warbird is a TNG term. Deep down I know that if TOS Romulans were using klingon D7s then surely movie era Klingons are using Romulan inspired "bird-of-preys" as part of a mutually beneficial alliance.  I don't care that there's no support for it past the name itself.  (And any pseudo prequels that contradict it are worthless to me.)

Comment: @lucasbachmann Wow, thank you for the reminder. I totally forgot that they were named differently. Now I'm trying to remember whether there were any smaller "warbirds" that looked like the ones in TOS.

Comment: I also learned that D'deridex class warbirds weren't in operation until the 2360s, so it would have been impossible for the assailants to be using D'deridex class ships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warbirds that attacked the Narendra III outpost were described in the EU novel [*Vulcan's Heart*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan%27s_Heart) as being [***Amarcan*** class](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Amarcan_class), a new type that made the previous [T'Liss class](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Liss_class) and Klingon-manufactured [K't'inga class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/K%27t%27inga_class) effectively obsolete.

> An image of a ship, the eagle on its underbelly freshly painted,
> formed on the screen, and Saavik straightened in alarm. This ship
> was perhaps twenty percent bigger than the old warbirds, with
> more graceful lines than the K’tinga-class Klingon vessels that
> the Empire had used in recent decades. [...]
>
> Old officers, some known even to Saavik thanks to intelligence
> briefings, appeared on screen, criticizing the quality of Klingon
> vessels and praising the space worthiness of the new ships.
>
> **The praetor reassumed control of the screen. “We are naming these
> ships Amarcan-class warbirds, after Commander Amarcan, late of the
> Imperial War College, who disappeared into the Barrier.**

Helpfully, we also get a glimpse of these ships on the book's cover

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. The Amarcan class kind of looks like a smaller D'deridex predecessor. Perhaps the former inspired the latter?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - Form likely follows function. The ship has 'warp wings' so it needs to look like a bird.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry: Frankly, this just looks like a simplified drawing of a D'deridex to me. Note that the Ambassador class similarly lacks any details. Chances are the artist totally ignored the fact that this was supposed to be a different ship type than the "TNG warbird".

Comment: @Valorum I wasn't wondering why the ships look like birds--and let's be honest, if they're willing to paint their ships with giant colorful decorative birds, then they had to have some aesthetic desires in mind when designing their ships--but what I was really wondering was if the design of the D'deridex was based on the Amarcan class. But O. R. Mapper made a good point. The artist probably had no idea what they were supposed to draw.